# How do i get rid of '-managedObjectContext' not found in protocol(s)

Tags: delegates, ios4, nsmanagedobjectcontext

my app runs on iPhone device and also in simulator. Everythings seems fine, but i see a compiler warning during build. I hate to deliver code thats not completely correct so i need to get rid of this warning. The compiler warning is:

newsReaderController.m:24: warning: '-managedObjectContext' not found in protocol(s)

The Code is:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //CORE DATA
    if (managedObjectContext == nil) { 
    managedObjectContext = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext]; 
    }
}
```

The managedObjectContext for CoreData operation is set up in App Delegate. Core Data Framework is importet and the app works like a charm.

any hint for me ? I'm working with objective-C for some weeks now but there seems to be something new to learn every day :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since `-[UIApplication delegate]` returns an object of type `id<UIApplicationDelegate>`, the compiler is complaining that no `-managedObjectContext` method exists in that one protocol. It's there, and you know it's there, so you can solve this issue by casting to your delegate's specific type (`MyAppDelegate` or whatever it may be called), or by casting to `id`:

```
 id appDelegate = (id)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
 managedObjectContext = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
```

Comment: Nice ! Thanks for being my teacher of the day ! This works like a charm !